# Overall complexity with multiple operations?

Tags: arrays, sorting, search, data-structures, time-complexity

If I have an unsorted array and if I first sort it by using quick sort with a run time of O(nlgn) and then search for an element using Binary search, with a run time of O(lgn) then what would be the over all run time of both these operations? Would that individual run times be added?

Answer (score 1):

It will be O(n logn) because O(n logn + logn) = O(n logn)
So yes, you sum it, but in this case it doesn't matter

> If the function f can be written as a finite sum of other functions, then the fastest growing one determines the order of f(n) 
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Would do you mean by it does not matter?

Comment: Because O(n logn) > O(logn) growth is defined as O(n logn), see the citation and the link in a post above

Comment: Oh ok got it! Thanks :)

Comment: A more reasonable complexity would be k binary searches performed after the sort, in which case you get O((n+k) log(n)).